# EOF when posting JSON to localhost Go backend using VueJS

Tags: json, vue.js, go

I'm setting up a login system using VueJS for frontend and Go for backend. I'm currently stuck at POSTing the username & password to the backend in JSON format.

Currently I am attempting to post using fetch, after having bad luck with Axios earlier.

Post method:

```
fetch("http://localhost:9444/login", {
                    method: "post",
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },

                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "emailAddress": "myName",
                        "password": "myPassword"
                    })
                })
                .then( (response) => { 
                console.log(response)
                });
```

Which I then route in my backend like:

```
r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
r.HandleFunc("/login", models.LoginHandler(db)).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")
```

LoginHandler:

```
func LoginHandler(db *sql.DB) func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        // w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        // Initialize loginInfo
        loginInfo := LoginInfo{}

        // Decode request body using JSON
        err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&loginInfo)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        println(loginInfo.EmailAddress)
        println(loginInfo.Password)

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte("Test message."))
    }
}
```

Which currently results in crashing on the decoding part like so:

```
2019/11/12 14:45:53 http: panic serving [::1]:57224: EOF
goroutine 35 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000196000)
        c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1769 +0x140
panic(0x8be000, 0xc00005c050)
        c:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1c3
_/H_/Development/clientportal/backend/models.LoginHandler.func1(0x9f7360, 0xc0001be000, 0xc0001a8200)
...
```

What could cause the constant EOF errors? I've tested (and confirmed correct functionality) using postman:

```
{
    "emailAddress": "login",
    "password": "passw"
}
```

Which returns status 200 correctly.

Comment: When you inspect the browser console do you see the request body empty?

Comment: You are assigning that handler for POST and OPTIONS, but you're not checking what type of request it is. Maybe it  is sending an OPTIONS before the POST?

Comment: @mkopriva Viewing the request using the Network tab, there's only request headers & general information.

Comment: @BurakSerdar results are exactly the same when not defining methods. It'll return 405 method not allowed if I remove only OPTIONS.

Comment: @Wessah, I realized you're calling the panic manually. The body is empty. Register your handler only for POST, there is no body for OPTIONS.

Comment: You need to accept OPTIONS (for CORS to work), but it should just return 200/204 and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (you can return others but this is the minimum). You can't just remove OPTIONS; you need to handle it appropriately (i.e. differently from POST).

Comment: Here's a good rundown on how CORS preflight works and why you need to handle OPTIONS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: @Adrian thank you very much! This made it work for me. I will answer the question with the working fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Adrian's comment I've got it working by accepting OPTIONS using the following code additions in my backend.

Routing:

```
r.HandleFunc("/login", models.LoginCORSHandler()).Methods("OPTIONS")
```

Handler:

```
// LoginCORSHandler handle OPTIONS request
func LoginCORSHandler() func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
}
```